# IntelliJ IDEA and Play framework integration - how to compile on edits?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.2

I created a Play/Activator project, and imported it into IntelliJ as an SBT project. The problem is that whenever I change the scala classes or the templates within IntelliJ, these are **not** automatically compiled (only when I refresh the page Play compiles the sources and I see the result correctly in the browser).

How to make IntelliJ compile scala and templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need ~

```
activator "~run 9000"
```

Comment: Could you be more explicit? Thanks

Comment: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/Getting-Started/Running.html
Read the section named Continuous Build and Test. The command above will start (run) the Play application at port 9000, and as soon as you edited and saved source code, sbt (activator) will automatically recompile (only) the changed files. If you do not want to run, but compile -> activator ~compile